# Does the order of additional "on" conditions in a join matter?

Tags: oracle

I'm working on joining 2 tables and want to join on multiple conditions but am wondering if the order of the conditions matter. Example below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_A A 
LEFT JOIN Table_B B
ON A.feature1 = B.Feature1
    AND A.feature2 = B.Feature2
    AND A.feature3 = B.Feature3
    AND A.feature4 = B.Feature4
```

Would the query above result in the same if the order of 'A.featureX = B.FeatureX' were any different? Thank you in advance!

I've tried changing the order expecting to see some difference but at least with the tables I'm working with I see nothing that has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, no, the order of join conditions and the order of predicates is irrelevant.

In practice, that is probably true the vast majority of the time that you're joining two tables.  But it gets less true the more tables you're joining and the more options the optimizer has to produce a query plan.  The optimizer has to produce a plan in milliseconds but the number of possible plans grows exponentially with the number of tables involved (and with the number of potential indexes).  That means that the optimizer has to use a variety of heuristics to figure out which plan trees to prune and which to explore.  And at some point, the plan tree that is found first because some join condition or predicate is considered first will get explored (or explored more deeply) than another plan tree that is considered later.  If you're building a giant query that joins 17 tables and has a bunch of predicates that could be satisfied by different indexes, there is a decent chance that changing the order of tables or the order of predicates or the order of join conditions would produce different query plans.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response, that makes sense to me. I will keep this in mind in the future if/when I join a large number of tables together.

Comment: @data_sci_engineer_97 I would say while it *may* influence a query plan, it is not what you may rely on, because this behaviour is not documented at all. The most common example of invalid expectation here is filtering by some text column with different domains in it (for example, key-value stored data) relying on "previous" predicate: while you may expect that `... type_col='DATE' and to_date(value_col, 'yyyymmdd') = another_date_col ..` will work fine, Oracle may decide to evaluate date comparison first and return an error like `ORA-01843 not a valid month`